# How to read response InputStream from spring boot controller to Ajax post method

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-boot

I created a spring boot application which includes form to submit data. On click submit button, File has to be downloaded. The response of spring controller is InputStream. how to convert the response of InputStream to zipped file using Ajax method?

Test.Controller class-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
headers="Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody InputStream downloadFile(@RequestBody Person person, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(FILE.getAbsoluteFile());
// code
try {
  inputStream.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
return inputStream;
}
```

Test.js-

```
 $('#button').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                 type : "POST",
                 data : formToJSON(),
                 url: "./test",
                 contentType: "application/json",
                 datatype : "json",
                 success: function(response) {
                     //need to download the file here by converting the inputStream to zipped file.
                      alert("success");
                 },
                  error : function(xhr, status, error)  {  
                      var err = xhr.responseText;
                      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = err;
                  }
               });
                return false;
            });

        });
```

Comment: you can send the zipped file from the controller instead of converting it in your javascript code

Comment: My requirement is such that, I need to return InputStream only as a response as this API is served for different purpose.